# Robocopy Files Only and Not Sub Folder Structures

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to Robocopy files from a directory that has about 100 subfolders with thousands of files in each subfolder to a Single Folder.
I don't need the subfolder structure, I just need the files out of each subfolder.

Is there a switch to exclude copying over the folder structures using just Robocopy?
I'm trying to stick with just Robocopy to eliminate any extra validation when doing custom code.

The is a sample of what I have together already and just need to plug in that exception.

robocopy SourceFolder DestinationFolder "keywordInFileName*" /S /COPY:DATSOU /DCOPY:DAT /IS /R:10 /W:5 /LOG+:C:\RoboCopyLog%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.txt

Can't find anything using just Robocopy.

Comment: So, you want to flatten the structure, and have all of the files copied into a single directory?  There's no switch to do that, because of the extreme danger of duplicates causing data loss.  It would be pretty easy to do a "dir /s" when you're done and use that to create a batch file of `move` commands.

Comment: Yes it is to a single directory. So I are you suggesting to do a robocopy script for each subfolder or is there some option in robocopy to.
1. get a list of the directories 
2. run the script above on that list of directories

Comment: There's going to be some coding involved.  You may be able to use `dir /s /ad /b` to get a list of the directory names, and use that to create a series of `robocopy` calls, but I'd use a scripting language.